# How to login in a site using python and download a PDF?

Tags: python

I have a site lets say xyz.com. User needs a username/password to log in. Now after login the user can see a few links for different PDF files. I need to automate this process of log in and download and save PDF to a particular location on my computer. How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: How are you asked for the password? BasicAuth or a more fancy user interface?

Comment: Its a JSP based website. So I am assuming its a basic JSP authentication.

Comment: To be honest I didn't try anything. You guys are right that I should give it a try first and then ask specific questions. I have see some answers on SO to login. I will try with those answers and ask again if I face any issues. Meanwhile is there a way to close or delete this question?

Comment: There should be a "delete" link right underneath the question.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your vague question, I'll give you a vague answer too.

You can use [Selenium Library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) to automate web browser interaction using Python.

Using Selenium library, one can access all functionalities of browser in an intuitive way. It allows the user to open, type, click, and etc..

You should [read the Selenium official docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html) to understand how you can achieve that. Or you can read it from [another source](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).

As an example, you could use some code like that to login in your *"xyz.org"* website.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("xyz.org/login.php") 
time.sleep(10)

username = browser.find_element_by_id("extpatid")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("extpatpw")

username.send_keys("your-username")
password.send_keys("your-password")

login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='submit']")
login_attempt.submit()
```

After submitting, you can search for the download link using the webdriver and then `.click()` it to download your file.